# Declaring a variable with two types: "int char"

Tags: c++, type-conversion, initialization, uniform-initialization, narrowing

I'm a C++ beginner, and I'm reading *Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++*.

In the section on *3.9.2 Unsafe conversions*, the author mentioned

> When the initializer is an integer literal, the compiler can check the actual value and accept values that do not imply narrowing:
>
> ```
> int char b1 {1000};     // error: narrowing (assuming 8-bit chars)
> ```

I'm puzzled by this declaration. It uses two types (`int` and `char`). I have never seen such declaration in Java and Swift before (the two languages I'm relatively familiar with). Is this a typo or a valid C++ syntax?

Comment: Which edition and printing of the book do you have? Have you looked for an errata of the book?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the reminder. I should definitely check the errata first.

Comment: So what version are you reading? I'm sure Bjarne would like to know about this mistake.

Comment: 3.9.2 Unsafe conversions
By unsafe conversion we mean that a value can be implicitly turned into a value of another type that does not equal the original value. e.g:

int i = 20000;
char c = i;
Such conversions are called 'narrowing' conversions.

double to int, char or bool
int to char or bool
char to bool

Comment: The `float char` is another useful type, especially in swimming pools.  Some come with a holder for a beer.

Comment: _Is this a typo or a valid C++ syntax?_ [Try it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pLqW3SiRSNyFad2a) (OK, OK, no it isn't valid).

Comment: @PaulSanders But then you encounter [stuff like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ah5TJ78ZcgO7JgYy) and are like... what?

Comment: @Izkata I don't understand - that's perfectly legal.  There's just a compiler warning for an unused variable.

Comment: @PaulSanders Think about it from a beginner's perspective:  It's still combining two datatypes, yet this one is legal for some reason.  (I'm not a C++-er and have no idea why that's legal and, for example, [this one isn't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c8ilMjt941q3uMWk))

Comment: @Izkata Oh, OK, I can explain that one for you.  `long long` is a distinct datatype in C / C++.  It is a 64 bit integer these days in practise, even on 32 bit platforms (the integer types are a bit of a mess generally, and there are now about 32767 of them because the standards guys keep making up new ones for no obvious reason).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It's a mistake in the book. That is not a valid C++ declaration, even without the supposed narrowing conversion.

It isn't mentioned in any of the erratas on [Bjarne Stroustrup's page](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2errata.html)(4th printing and earlier), though, which is odd. It's a clear enough mistake. I imagine since it's commented with `//error` few people notice the mistake in the declaration itself.

Comment: What was probably the intended code example in the book?

Comment: @Hamsterrific `char b1 {1000};` (because that would provoke the error mentioned in the comment). I guess Bjarne's typing fingers were tired that day.

Comment: @PaulSanders Tired? He typed an extra `int` there! :-)

Comment: @ LeoHeinsaar Lol.  OK, too much coffee then :)  Or maybe he has a stutter :)

Comment: Yeah: fingers tired. It looks like a cut-n-paste error from the example that preceded it. In that prior example, he gives two lines:

int a {1000}; // OK [\n]
char b {a} // error: int -> char might narrow [\n]

and he seems to have cut-n-pasted that example for the next one and missed deleting the "int" part:

int char b1 {1000}; // error: narrowing (assuming 8-bit chars) [\n]
char b2 {48}; // OK [\n]

Answer (score 24):

The book is wrong.

The token sequence `int char b1{1000};` is not semantically valid C++.

You are trying to declare `b1` with more than one type, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 10):

It is wrong.
In C/C++ the multi-type declarations can be achieved via the use of unions. Eg:

```
union {
    int i;
    char c;
} var;

var.i = 42;
/* OR */
var.c = ‘c’;
```

The storage is the same, so .c and .i are just per-type handles to the same value.

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong in C/C++ syntax. In addition to `union`s (see @Alex answer), there is a C++ way to store only one of available types called [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (type-safe union):

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, float> v, w;
    v = 12; // v contains int
    int i = std::get<int>(v);
    w = std::get<int>(v);
    w = std::get<0>(v); // same effect as the previous line
    w = v; // same effect as the previous line

//  std::get<double>(v); // error: no double in [int, float]
//  std::get<3>(v);      // error: valid index values are 0 and 1

    try {
      std::get<float>(w); // w contains int, not float: will throw
    }
    catch (std::bad_variant_access&) {}

    std::variant<std::string> v("abc"); // converting constructors work when unambiguous
    v = "def"; // converting assignment also works when unambiguous
}
```